# jquery library to count how many times a user has logged into my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am using a jquery library for cookies and want to use this cookie to count how many times a user has logged into my page.

The cookies I am using are here: https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

and I am setting the cookies within a login function.

The problem is I want to pass a counter within `Cookies.set(` or have some sort of mechanism within this where the cookie will remember how many times the user has logged in.

Please can someone help with this?

Comment: show us your code

Comment: I don't know what you need this for and how exact the results must be, but don't expect any reliable results with cookies, as they might be cleaned out (or blocked) by the user. If you're using database for login in, you could create extra column for login counter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check if have that coockie in the page. If true, get the coockie value and add to it 1. Else, set this coocike first time in value 1:

```
count = parseInt(Cookies.get('counter'));
if(count){
    Cookies.set('counter', count + 1);
}
else{
    Cookies.set('counter', 1);
}
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I want but I think the count is taken as a string and 1 is appended so it displays as 1111 for 4 times visited. I need to know how to change it to 4 rather that four 1s. Thanks for your help